# How to change the date for datetime index to begining of the month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe having DatetimeIndex as below:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-27', '2013-08-03', '2013-08-10', '2013-08-17',
               '2013-08-24', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-07', '2013-09-14',
               '2013-09-21', '2013-09-28',
               ...
               '2018-11-03', '2018-11-10', '2018-11-17', '2018-11-24',
               '2018-12-01', '2018-12-08', '2018-12-15', '2018-12-22',
               '2018-12-29', '2019-01-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='wdate', length=285, freq=None)
```

I want to change each date to the begining of the month I.e. 2013-07-27 should change to 2013-07-01
How do I do that using pandas dataframe in python?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using MonthBegin is that it converts date 1 to date 1 of previous month. Check the last date in the index.

```
i = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-27', '2013-08-03', '2013-08-10', '2013-08-17',
       '2013-08-24', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-07', '2013-09-14',
       '2013-09-21', '2013-09-28',
       '2018-11-03', '2018-11-10', '2018-11-17', '2018-11-24',
       '2018-12-01', '2018-12-08', '2018-12-15', '2018-12-22',
       '2018-12-29', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-01'])

i - pd.to_timedelta(df.index.day - 1, unit='d')

DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-08-01',
               '2013-08-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-09-01',
               '2013-09-01', '2013-09-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-01',
               '2018-11-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01',
               '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', '2019-01-01',
               '2019-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```